# Single resource file for DataAnnotations localization

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

What I should try to achieve is to have a single resource (resx) file for each supported language in **net-core**. I explain the problem a bit.

I have DataAnnotations on each of my entities and I need to localize the messages returned in case of errors. It seems that the default convention required by **net-core** is to have a different resx file for each of our entities.

This file is named accordingly to the namespace of the entity with the culture indentifier and the resx extensions. So, if I have an entity named *Customers* within the namespace *Data.Entities*, I should add a file named *Data.Entities.Customers.it.resx* and put all the translations for the Italian language in it. So, if I have an attribute

```
StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="The {0} should not be longer than {1} characters") 
public string Name {get;set;}
```

then I add the proper translation to the *Data.Entities.Customers.it.resx* file.

But, if I go on another entitity like *Suppliers* I am forced to write another resource file named *Data.Entities.Suppliers.it.resx* and, of course I have

```
StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="The {0} should not be longer than {1} characters") 
public string SupplierName {get;set;}
```

Now I need to write again the same translation in the proper file for the Suppliers entity. This goes on as well for other common attributes like [Required].

So I hope to have explained well my problem and my queston is: There is a way to specify a single resource file for all my entities validation messages and then write a single time the messages for the common texts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#using-one-resource-string-for-multiple-classes), you can tell the framework to use a shared resource for your data annotations localisation:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
            options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
        });
}
```

> In the preceeding code, `SharedResource` is the class corresponding to the resx where your validation messages are stored. With this approach, `DataAnnotations` will only use `SharedResource`, rather than the resource for each class.

Comment: Ouch, I have read that doc at the beginning (when I had other concerns) and now this escaped to me totally. Let me try a bit

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Comment: Do the resx files need to use a specific Build Action? Do I have to declare an empty SharedResource type with the same namespace? I can't manage to make this work (ASP.NET Core 2.1).

Comment: Not sure what is your problemwith 2.1, I got this working flawlessy with 1.1. You add an empty public class somewhere in your namespace and use it in the typeof above. The resx file has Embedded Resources as BuildAction. The name for the resx file is composed with the namespace of the class. For example, if the class is named SharedResources inside the namespace Dto. then your resource files is named Dto.SharedResource.it.resx. Conventions I suppose.

Comment: @Steve I believe if you use a different overload of [`factory.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.istringlocalizerfactory.create?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Localization_IStringLocalizerFactory_Create_System_String_System_String_), you can specify the name manually.